# Authentication failed when deploy an Analysis Services project

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssas

I am getting the following error on Analysis Services project on Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2014:

> The project could not be deployed to the 'MyServerName\InstanceName'
>   server because of the following connectivity problems : 
>   Authentication failed.  To verify or update the name of the target
>   server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select
>   Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the
>   name of the server.

- On Project-> properties -> Deployment -> Server it has the ServerName\InstanceName properly, using the same ServerName\InstanceName on SSMS I can connect without problem.
- On Data Source I tested the connection and it passed successfully
- Changed the Impersonator user to my user which is Sysadmin

I google it, but all references I found isn't Autentication failure.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT
If I execute

```
telnet ipServer 2382
```

successfully connects.

I tried with VS2019 and had the same error.

Tried using service account for impersonator, and the user services is administrator on server and sysadmin but also get the same error.

Also I checked [this](http://www.msbiguide.com/ssas-error-a-connection-cannot-be-made-ensure-the-server-is-running/) guide and no one of those fixes helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after try a lot of things and post on microsoft [forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1db96294-5a6d-45b3-ad5c-f440f97f801c/authentication-failed-analysis-services-deployment?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

The problem was I was trying to deploy from my computer to a server on another domain and need to use a domain account, doesn't matter if you can connect to SQL instance.

I don't know why "Use services Account" didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

> I was trying to deploy from my computer to a server on another domain

The connection to SSAS to deploy always uses Windows Authentication, and always uses the account for Visual Studio.  To deploy to an SSAS server in another domain (or no domain), launch SSAS with 'runas /netonly' providing the target domain credentials.

This will launch Visual Studio without impersonation, but using the specified credentials for all network access.